Compile With MSVC Missing __has_builtin
I'm trying to write some platform-independent code to programmatically pop a breakpoint. I found std::breakpoint which of course doesn't exist until C++26. I looked further into the proposal and found the reference implementation. I adapted it a bit to include defaulting to the std version for a dream of future-proofing, but started in with the first bit of the reference which has a nifty bit of preprocessor work that includes the use of __has_builtin, which I'd never seen before. Here's where I got to:
// If later than C++23, we can use the standard breakpoint function.
#if defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus > 202302L
  #include <debugging>
  #define breakpoint() std::breakpoint_if_debugging()
#endif

// Check if compiler has an already-available builtin debug breaking function.
#if !defined(breakpoint) && defined(__has_builtin) && !defined(__ibmxl__)
  #if __has_builtin(__builtin_debugtrap)
    #define breakpoint() __builtin_debugtrap()
  #elif __has_builtin(__debugbreak)
    #define breakpoint() __debugbreak()
  #endif
#endif

// Failed to get a breakpointing function.
#if !defined(breakpoint)
  #error There wasn't a simple breakpoint method.
#endif

Lo and behold, intellisense believes that the __has_builtin(__debug_break) path will be all I need to get a definition for breakpoint (for Windows at least). I tried compiling to check and immediately hit the error path instead.

I can't find anything explicitly detailing the existence of __has_builtin while using MSVC but as I understand __debug_break is an MSVC-only builtin. Am I misunderstanding something here? Is this for clang on Windows?
Is there a compiler option I need to enable to get __has_builtin?
Hovering over __has_builtin(__debugbreak) has intellisense showing that it expands to 1. Is this just the classic intellisense lying? It also shows __has_builtin as a "predefined dynamic macro", which sounds like it really means "magic function the compiler handles".


Consider anything starting with __  to be non-portable (and you shouldn't use variables/functions prefixed with double underscores it your code ever). Note that visual studio does not use it's own compiler for intellisense so some of its warnings/errors are inconsistent with actual compilation

Yes, I understand that it's non-portable. The question isn't about the code itself, it's about the __has_builtin macro's existence in an MSVC compilation specifically. Even outside of this, what the code is trying to do isn't possible outside of non-portable solutions until C++26.

Oh ok, my mistunderstanding.  But the remark about intellisense is still valid ;)

Absolutely, intellisense has bitten all of us a ton of times. This is just the latest instance making me sad.

Doesn't look like msvc supports __has_builtin, you're probably better off just checking for which compiler you're using instead. Note that __cplusplus isn't a good way to check for a c++ feature availablity, a compiler may claim c++26 support but not support std::breakpoint, you should use the feature test macro listed on the cppreference page

Intellisense uses a compiler that knows and supports __has_builtin, but the main compiler does not.

Is __debugbreak not an MSVC-only builtin? Weird that the reference implementation for this feature would waste time on using an incompatible set of builtins to check for availability.
@AlanBirtles Thanks, I'll use that instead.

I think that you can just do #ifdef _MSC_VER. This is common for MSVC's builtins.

Yes, this is the solution from the reference implementation. Just not sure why they check __has_builtin, as I said before.

@Braaedy Because of clang-cl. Updated answer.

MSVC doesn't support __has_builtin.
A workaround is #ifdef _MSC_VER(or #if _MSC_VER >= xxx). People have been doing this for years to detect MSVC's builtins.


Yes, this is the solution from the reference implementation. Just not sure why they check __has_builtin, as I said before.

Because Clang supports __has_builtin and has a cl driver-mode, a.k.a clang-cl, which tries to be compatible with MSVC and supports __debugbreak.
